# On which of the programming SE's should I ask about coding conventions/practices?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was about to ask about the best way to comment something, and I found myself about to post on Programmers when I decided that it didn't seem to fit into the topics laid out [there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Is there a tag on either site that would apply?

Comment: You might find [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) suitable.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Definitely programmers.